# EF 6.0 Code First: How to Synchronize an existing database with existing domain classes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I apologize in advance for what could be an obvious question, but I'm new to Entity Framework.

I Have an EF Code First project which is in a specific assembly : `MyStuff.Persistence`

It uses **existing domain classes** from: `MyStuff.Domain`

I've the ability to modify `MyStuff.Domain` which will be exposed thru `MyStuff.Service`

I want to synchronize my EF 6.0 code first project with an **existing database**

So, I decided to follow this tutorial : 
[Code First From Database MSDN guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx),

The problem is that It creates the domain classes in `MyStuff.Persistence`, superseding the existing ones in `MyStuff.Domain`

What can I do to synchronize both existing elements(database/domain)?
 I've read about Fluent API by googling, but I can't find this exact use case.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you are looking for data migrations. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persistence and Domain are the same thing in code first - it's the set of classes that define your database and are also used to interact with it via the context. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database#7579835

If your database already exists, reverse engineer it and move the POCO classes where you want (MyStuff.Domain) and move the generated model code into your context. This includes an OnModelCreating() override with fluent api code that defines any relationships EF can't figure out by convention (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx).

As to keeping things in sync, EF will build a model from your classes and compare that to the database. If they are different what happens will depend on your initializer (http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods). You might choose to use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in early development. In this case EF will drop your database (including existing data) and recreate it based on your models and fluent code. You can use a Seed() method of the initializer to repopulate any test data you might need.

Once you are up and running for a while, you probably won't want to use this technique and instead would switch to something like database migrations which uses the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer. With this you could develop as normal and perhaps enable AutomaticMigrations (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx). When you need to update a different database you generate a SQL script to bring it in sync with your development database.

Comment: Thank you for a clear description of all the processes involved in code first from an existing database.